# Nested Select Resultset in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am new to SQL within Oracle. I have a really simple need of manipulating the output of a Select statement within another Select.
SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT User_State FROM
(
 SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, ..... , STAT_CD || '-' || STAT_NM "User_State"
 FROM TABLE_NAME
 ORDER BY COLUMN_1
)
```

The error I am getting:
**ORA-00904: "User_State": invalid identifier**.
How do I access columns from the output of inner SQL from the outer in Oracle? I think this worked in MySQL.

Comment: `User_State` and `"User_State"` are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use double quotes.  In fact, you can more simply do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT STAT_CD || '-' || STAT_NM as User_State
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

The `ORDER BY` is ignored anyway, so it is not relevant.  Even if Oracle guaranteed that an `ORDER BY` in the subquery would be recognized in the outer query (which it does not), the `SELECT DISTINCT` undoes the ordering anyway.